# Edit a file in docker container from outside the container?

Tags: docker

I have one docker container, that container is running in weblogic11 so that Weblogic is running by default in Production-mode, so I want to change that production-mode to Development-mode, for that I need to edit file `config.xml` inside the container, how we can edit that file from outside the container?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you can do that. There's docker configuration called `mounting`. To mount the file inside container, add -v parameter on your `docker run` command:

```sh
docker run -d -v /path/to/your-file.xml:/path/to/file/inside/container-shoulbe.xml image:version
```

or if you are using docker-compose, your `docker-compose.yml` should be like this:

```
...
services:
    web:
        image: xxx:version
        volumes:
            ...
            - /path/to/your-file.xml:/path/to/file/inside/container-shoulbe.xml
...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by mounting your volumes.  E.g

```
services:
    web:
        image: your_image:tag
        volumes:
          - app_config:/locaiton_of_config_folder

volumes:
  app_config:
```

This will create docker volumes and it will be mounted at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_name/_data` and you can edit the files.  Be sure to use `sudo` because the files are created by root user inside docker.

You can check the list of volumes by `docker volume ls`.

Answer (score 2):

**There is one quite simple workaround to doing that.**

You want to copy out the file from the running container:

```html
docker cp <container_id>:/path/to/file .
```

You could edit the file with whatever you want, and you just should copy it back:

```html
docker cp file <container_id>:/path/to/file
```

---

*Optional:* if you want your file to be persisted, you just need to commit the changes:

```html
docker commit <container_id> <new_image_name>
```